# php mysqli : if data_seek() is the setter, the getter is...?

Tags: php, mysqli

if data_seek is the resultset's pointer setter, is there a way to get the current line?

```
SELECT * FROM xxx ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10

$m->data_seek(9); // last item

$last = $m->fetch_object();

echo $m->........; // must echo 9
```

Comment: are you talking about $current_field??

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there is no native way to do this, you could, however, extend mysqli_result in order to implement such functionallity... which forces you to extend the main mysqli class as well.

- $result->current_field only works if you get your field information
  using $result->fetch_field()

**something like this for the result class**

```
class extended_mysqli_result extends mysqli_result
{
    public $last_seek = 0;

    public function data_seek($offset = 0)
    {
        parent::data_seek($this->last_seek = $offset);
    }
}
```

**and something like this for the main class**

```
class extended_mysqli extends mysqli
{
    public function query( $query )
    {
        if ( $this->real_query($query) )
        {
            if ( $this->field_count )
            {
                return new extended_mysqli_result($this);
            }
            else return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```